# How to display products in site that are out of stock

Tags: product, ce-1.7.0.2, configurable-product, product-attribute, stock

On my Magento site I have configurable products. They have `size` and `color` attributes. How can I display products with sizes and colors that are out of stock? Now you can select only the color from from the products in stock and size also. If product is out of stock, combination of color/size isn't available for choosing. How to display all colors and sizes even from simple products out of stock?

P.S. I already set the configuration `Display Out of Stock Products` to Yes, but this is probably for catalog display, not attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto

> Mage / Catalog / Block / Product / View / Type / Configurable.php

```
public function getAllowProducts()
{
    if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()) {
        $products = array();
        $skipSaleableCheck = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck();
        $allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getUsedProducts(null, $this->getProduct());
        foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
            if ($product->isSaleable() || $skipSaleableCheck) {
                $products[] = $product;
            }
        }
        $this->setAllowProducts($products);
    }
    return $this->getData('allow_products');
}
```

Replace with this

```
public function getAllowProducts()
{
    if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()) {
        $products = array();
        $skipSaleableCheck = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck();
        $allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getUsedProducts(null, $this->getProduct());
        foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
            $products[] = $product;
        }
        $this->setAllowProducts($products);
    }
    return $this->getData('allow_products');
}
```

**Note:** Don't Edit in Core files. Make rewrite or copy the folder structure in to local code pool.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. If I edit core file it works. Can you help me with overriding it?
I created the file `app/code/local/SpartakusMd/CustomProductImporter/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php` with the class 
 `class SpartakusMd_CustomProductImporter_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable`, but it doesn't seem to override it. What is wrong?

Comment: Oooh, I forgot about `config.xml`. What shoud I insert there?

Comment: @SpartakusMd there is another way. You can copy the Same folder structure in local. like `local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php`